# Paperclip using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, paperclip

I have a Rails 3.2 application in which I use paperclip to upload and store file attachments. This works great in itself, but I want to test it using rspec.

Now, the documentation provides some pretty nifty shoulda matchers to do just that. However, when I try to run them, it says my configuration in the spec helper is wrong:

```
uninitialized constant Paperclip::Shoulda (NameError)
```

I have the following in my spec helper:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Paperclip::Shoulda::Matchers
end
```

And this is in my Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.0"
  gem "shoulda-matchers"
end
```

I am not sure what I am missing here?

Comment: Do you have `require 'paperclip/matchers'` in the spec helper file?

Comment: I do. And I found out what the problem was. I had that behind the shoulda matchers, but instead I first need to require the paper clip matchers, and only afterwards include the shoulda matchers. Thanks for pushing me in the right direction! If you want, add that as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. I had `require 'paperclip/matchers'` behind the shoulda matchers, but instead I first need to require the paper clip matchers, and only afterwards include the shoulda matchers.